# Allow public to post on blog

Tags: posts, users

I need public users to be able to submit posts, then have them be approved by a moderator or admin on the dashboard. Is this possible to do? I would like it to function very similarly to comments.

for example, users will post their own stories and then a moderator will approve it being posted.

I am new to this particular stackexchange (I use stackoverflow often) and wordpress development, so forgive me if this seems like a stupid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to give users access to the WordPress admin screens and you don't want to use a premium plugin, you should create a form in a page and use [wp_insert_post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post) with the submitted data.

In your case, the "post_status" parameter could be used to "moderate":

```
$post = array(
    'post_title'   => $_POST['title_field'],
    'post_content' => $_POST['content_field'],
    'post_status'  => [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ] //Set the status of the new post.
);

wp_insert_post($post);
```

The **wp_insert_post** function should take care of sanitizing the data before inserting it into the DB, but I recommend to double check and [add filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation) if necessary.

Comment: I think you have to `register_post_status()` first.

Comment: @gyo would I create a separate PHP file to handle this form action and contain this code? Also, do I need to use register_post_status() as Max indicated? And if so, where would I put that?

Comment: Yep, use "register_post_status" for custom "statuses",  not necessary if you use "draft". I'd submit the form via [Ajax](http://wp.tutsplus.com/articles/getting-started-with-ajax-wordpress-pagination/), or alternatively in your page-template place the logic inside an **if (isset($_POST))** block.

Answer (score 0):

The only plugin that I know of that supports this is [Gravity Forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/).

This tutorial should also be mostly relevant. 
http://yoast.com/gravity-forms-custom-post-types/